# Dovecot "Can't load SSL certificate"

Tags: dovecot, certificate

I've been spending a LOT of time trying to get Dovecot working. It keeps throwing the following messages when attempting to connect:

```
May 15 02:55:20 yoshi128k dovecot: imap-login: Error: Failed to initialize SSL server context: Can't load SSL certificate: error:14187180:SSL routines:ssl_do_config:bad value: section=system_default
May 15 02:55:20 yoshi128k dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected: TLS initialization failed. (no auth attempts in 0 secs)
```

Here's the output of doveconf -n:

```
# 2.3.4.1 (f79e8e7e4): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.4 ()
doveconf: Warning: NOTE: You can get a new clean config file with: doveconf -Pn > dovecot-new.conf
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:25: 'imaps' protocol is no longer necessary, remove it
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:25: 'pop3s' protocol is no longer necessary, remove it
# OS: Linux 4.19.0-16-amd64 x86_64 Debian 10.9 ext4
# Hostname: yoshi128k.mooo.com
auth_mechanisms = plain login
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n/
mail_privileged_group = mail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
postmaster_address = postmaster at yoshi128k.tk
protocols = imap pop3 lmtp
service auth-worker {
  user = vmail
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  user = dovecot
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 110
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
    port = 995
    ssl = yes
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.crt
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key_password = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_min_protocol = SSLv3
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
  driver = static
}
```

I do have 10-ssl.conf pointing to my certificate files, so I'm not too sure what's going on.

EDIT: Here's the output of OpenSSL's s_client:

```
root@yoshi128k:/etc/postfix# openssl s_client -connect mail.yoshi128k.tk:143 -starttls imap
CONNECTED(00000003)
139987247760512:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 345 bytes and written 345 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: Have you tried upgrading OpenSSL? Might be an OpenSSL bug.

Comment: It's already up to date.

Comment: Try changing `ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.yoshi128k.tk/cert.pem` to `ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.yoshi128k.tk/fullchain.pem`, and ensure that the key is set to the corresponding private key file. Your openssl connect command indicates that the server does in fact not send a certificate.

Comment: I actually switched to a self-signed certificate generated with OpenSSL:
I'll update the main post with the updated config.

Comment: Again, my config above has been updated, and is now reflected in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem all along was an invalid entry in openssl.cnf